# problem with ls in ~/Downloads directory

Tags: macos, command-line, iterm, zsh

How can I fix the broken `ls` command in the ~/Download directory in macOS?

```
 ~/Downloads  ls                                          ✔  at 02:01:06 PM
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the `chmod` command (and following "Operation not permitted" errors) before you execute the `ls` command?

Comment: @IconDaemon I followed the suggestion of this comment but no luck https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/8568070#gistcomment-4017862

Comment: From your home directory, do a `ls -ld Downloads`  and a `stat Downloads` and add the output to your question.